# Processes keep on closing shortly after they are started (more details in the Description)

Tags: windows-10

**General Information**

- Mainboard:    MSI X370 Gaming Pro Carbon
- CPU:      3800 XT
- GPU:      ASUS ROG STRIX 2080 Super
- PSU:      650 W Xilence 80+ Gold
- RAM:      16 GB Dual Channel G.Skill Ripjaws
- Storage:      1 TB M.2 SSD, 240 GB M.2 (Empty)
- OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Education
- OS Version:                10.0.19042 N/A Build 19042
- Install Date      12/03/2021, 14:07:26

**Let's start with an example:**

1. Launch ts3client_win64.exe with safemode parameter
2. Shortly after it terminates (?) *Please correct me if that is the wrong term*
3. When I look into process explorer, there are multiple processes suspended of ts3client_win64.exe

If needed I can provide a Video of this.

- This has happened before but it stopped for a few days so I thought okay that was strange and today it happened again so I decided to create a post and find a solution before I reinstall my windows.
- This does not only happen to Teamspeak 3.
- This also happens to other processes BUT not to all.

**So in general:**
Some processes can run without problems.
Some "crash" right after starting them.

**I already tried:**

- Restarting multiple times
- Check for Windows Updates
- Scanning my 1 TB SSD Drive with CHKDSK
- Scan my Memory with memtest till 400%
- Running Programs as admin doesn't change anything
- Scan my PC with Malewarebytes
- Look in Process Explorer if there is a match with Virustotal.com

List of Programs that **don't** work which I found so far:

- HWINFO64 and 32
- CPU-Z
- Teamspeak 3 Client
- Spotify
- services.msc
- devmgmt.msc
- Notepad++
- Notepad.exe
- Visual Studio Code
- all commands ran in RUN window (WIN + R)

List of Programs that **do** work which I found so far:

- Visual Studio
- Discord
- Powershell
- CMD
- OBS Studio
- Process Explorer
- Explorer

I am lost for ideas what this could be caused by.

What information can I provide to help?

I apologize for any English mistakes.

I appreciate any effort of help :)!

Comment: You might check the Eventlog for any errors (especially the "Application" and "System" Logs. Since other MMC plugins like service.msc not working you might get troubles to get EventViewer runnning since being eventvwr.msc at all. If so, you might copy Application.evtx and System.evtx (located in C:\WINDOWS\system32\winevt\logs) and open it on another computer (if available)

Comment: Can you run Process Monitor to capture the process exit code?  I'm suspecting a fast fail error - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190108-00/?p=100655 Otherwise, can you create a dump by doing the following: 1 - Create `C:\dumps`. 2. Download procdump.exe to it. 3. Run `procdump -ma -i C:\dumps`. 4 Launch a process, hopefully it crashes and creates a dump.  5. Run `procdump -u` to unregister procdump.

Comment: Ok thanks I will try this and then give feedback :)!

Comment: Thank you because of your help I was able to fix the problem :)! I will edit my post to add the Solution

Answer (score 0):

**________________________________________________________________**

**SOLUTION:**

So thanks to HelpingHand and Willy K. I was able to find a Solution.

I follwed the steps provided and took a look at the dump files for multiple programs that crashed. The error code was always the same: The thread tried to read from or write to a virtual address for which it does not have the appropriate access. (0xC0000005)

I wondered because even notepad.exe crashed and it said the exception source was C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\GPU TweakII\GTII-OSD\x64\GTII-OSD64-VK.dll

So I decided to uninstall ASUS GPU Tweak II and now everything works fine again.

Very strange.
Thanks for the help :))!

**TLDR:** ASUS GPU Tweak II caused the problem -> uninstalled it and it was fine.

**________________________________________________________________**